# Selecting row from table meeting two count conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, count, having

I have a table that consists out of Users, Exercises and a Score. Below one can see the structure of the table and some example data (just to give you an idea).

`|UserID | ExerciseID | Score |`
`------------------------------`
`|1      | 1          | 0     |`
`|1      | 2          | 1     |`
`|2      | 1          | 1     |`
`|2      | 2          | 0     |`

This table contains around 92000 ratings (each row is a unique pair of three). I want to receive a subset of this table with the most active users **and** exercises. Most active means for example occurring more than 20 times in the table. So I want users that have completed more than 20 different exercises and I want exercises that have been completed more than 20 times by different users.

It's a bit of a circular reasoning as I'd like users that have completed 20 or more different *active* exercises, those exercises have to be active as they should be completed by 20 or more users and those users should be active and so on and so on..

I'm hoping this is achievable by a query, I've tried myself and come up with a query that comes close to result I want, but the results are not entirely accurate (as there is one user that has only completed 16 exercises and 2 exercises that have been completed 19 times by other users). The query is somewhat ugly but here it is:

```
select UserID, ExerciseID, Score
from [FrenchExercises]
where ExerciseID in (   select ExerciseID
                    from [FrenchExercises]
                    where UserID in (SELECT UserID
                                        FROM [FrenchExercises]
                                        GROUP BY UserID
                                        HAVING count(ExerciseID) >= 20)
                    group by ExerciseID
                    having count(UserID) >= 20)
    AND UserID in ( select UserID
                    from [FrenchExercises]
                    where ExerciseIDin (SELECT ExerciseID
                                        FROM [FrenchExercises]
                                        GROUP BY ExerciseID
                                        HAVING count(UserID) >= 20)
                    group by UserID
                    having count(ExerciseID) >= 20)
```

The first subquery selects the most active users and then selects the most active exercises with users from the active user list. The second query does the same thing from an exercise  perspective where it selects the most active exercises and then selects the most active users having selected these exercises. When I want to combine both queries and select ExerciseID, UserID and Score I see that results aren't entirely correct.

I'm guessing my query has some mistake or I'm taking an entirely wrong approach. Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: Why not just `select UserID, count(distinct ExerciseID) as exercises
from [FrenchExercises]
group by UserID`

and

`select ExerciseID, count(distinct UserID) as users
from [FrenchExercises]
group by ExerciseID`

Comment: @juergend - He does not want separate results. He wants the query which shows most active users who have answered the most "active" questions. So, its not such a simple answer.

Comment: This sounds like co-clustering, which would be a bit tricky in SQL Server.

Comment: @juergend Borat Sagdiyev is right, I do not want the results separately.

Gordon Linoff, any thoughts on how to handle in SQL Server? Or is it better to resolve to a different method?

Comment: What is an "active user"? Is it any user who has done 20+ exercises?

Comment: What is an "active exercise"? is it any that have has 20+ users? & This is the only condition (for that phrase)

Comment: An active user is a user that has completed 20 active exercises or more. An active exercise is an exercise that has been completed by 20 active users or more.  
  
Basically what I want to be able to do on the result set is the following two queries: `select UserID, count(ExerciseID) from RESULTS group by UserID` and `select ExerciseID, count(UserID) from RESULTS group by ExerciseID`. With these two queries you can check in the results whether your users are active and whether your exercises are active.

Answer (score 0):

Edit based on some comments:

```
select userid, exerciseid, score
  from frenchexercises
 where userid in (select userid
                    from frenchexercises
                   group by userid
                  having count(*) >= 20)
   and exerciseid in (select exerciseid
                        from frenchexercises
                       group by exerciseid
                      having count(distinct userid) >= 20)
```

**Fiddle demonstration:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a2cc6/6/0

In the example data I have USERID #1 performing 20 exercises. Exercises #1 through #20. Only one of those exercises is an "active" one. Exercise #1 is performed by 20 other people, in addition to user #1, so it's active. The rest are not.

User #1 is returned in the output, but only exercise #1 is listed, because that's the only active exercise he performs.

**The difference between this query and my previous query is that user #1 would not have been considered active because he does not participate in 20 or more ACTIVE exercises. He only participates in 20 or more ANY exercises.** That is what I changed.

In case the latter is indeed what you actually intended, here is the previous query:

```
select userid, exerciseid, score
  from frenchexercises
 where userid in (select userid
                    from frenchexercises
                   where exerciseid in
                         (select exerciseid
                            from frenchexercises
                           group by exerciseid
                          having count(distinct userid) >= 20)
                   group by userid
                  having count(*) >= 20)
   and exerciseid in (select exerciseid
                        from frenchexercises
                       group by exerciseid
                      having count(distinct userid) >= 20)
```

Again, **the above query will only consider a user active IF they also participate in 20+ active exercises.**

Comment: In both approaches only the active users are selected and not the active exercises. I need something that selects them both.

Comment: @FlorisDevriendt the query did provide users who perform 20 or more active exercises (correctly) but did not also limit -- for such users -- the results from showing other 'inactive exercises' they might also participate in. I just changed my answer to address that last part.

Comment: Both queries provide me with users who have performed 20 or more active exercises. That is correct. However the queries do not return active exercises, it only returns active users that have performed on active exercises (alongside with any other exercise). What I want is to have **both** active users (who have worked on active exercises) and active exercises (who have been completed by active users).

Comment: @FlorisDevriendt I changed my answer after your initial comment. Ie. I added a subquery that further filters the results to only active exercises that have been completed by active users.

Comment: @FlorisDevriendt the above query only considers a user as active if they completed 20 or more ACTIVE exercises, which is what I thought you wanted; is that the case or no?

Comment: @FlorisDevriendt I changed the query to consider a user active if they complete at least 20 exercises (ANY exercise, not just those that are active), and for those active users, it lists only those active exercises that they perform (they must perform at least one active exercise (not 20)). Hopefully that is what you want.

Comment: The query does what you want it to do. But it does not what I want it to do. The results from this query will give me active users that worked on active exercises. But in the results, I can have exercises where only one of those users has worked on (it's possible the exercise has been worked on by more 20 users, which makes it an active exercises, however it has not been worked on by 20 active users).

Comment: I'm aware that I'm not so good at explaining this. My question is somewhat circular as in my results I want active users AND active exercises. In other words, the records that will be returning should ONLY include users that have completed 20 or more exercises from the resulting records AND the exercises in the resulting exercises should be exercises that have been worked on by more than 20 users that appear in the resulting records. The results I'm getting now includes exercises that have not been completed 20 times or more by active users only.

Comment: @FlorisDevriendt I believe the query does exactly that. Given the example data, user 1 participates in 20 exercises. 1 of those exercises is performed by 20+ users. He is the only person returned by that query AND only the exercise that is performed by 20+ users is returned. That is exactly what you just described.

Comment: @FlorisDevriendt Given the example data in my fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a2cc6/6/0 what output do you expect?

Comment: Yes, I agree on that, your query does work on the example data you provided. However on my data their appears to be cases where it adds more exercises then it should. Let me see if I can reproduce the results on a smaller dataset on the sql fiddle. I'll post later when I find it.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like I'm missing some nuance, but to my simplistic mind this is what I have focused on:

- Most active means for example occurring more than 20 times in the
  table. ...
- and I want exercises that have been completed more than 20 times by
  different users.

I have made the assumption that there are no duplicates of UserID & ExcerciseID in this table; So a count of users against exercise is distinct and a count of exercises against users is distinct.

My approach is to use COUNT() OVER() to supply the wanted counts are supplied on a record by record basis, then filter the records.

```
DECLARE @cutoff int
SET @cutoff = 20

SELECT
      UserId
    , ExerciseID
    , Score
FROM (
            SELECT
                  UserId
                , ExerciseID
                , Score
                , COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY UserID)     AS ExcerciseUsers
                , COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY ExerciseID) AS UserExcercises
            FROM FrenchExercises
      ) AS derived
WHERE ExcerciseUsers >= @cutoff
      AND UserExcercises >= @cutoff
ORDER BY
      UserId
      , ExerciseID
;
```

<kbd>[Demo1 - small sample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b3ba9/1)</kbd>
<kbd>[Demo2 - tast case by Brian DeMilia](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a2cc6/23)</kbd>

In reviewing this perhaps I had overlooked "*have been completed*", and assuming a Score of 1 indicates complete then the following takes this into account:

```
DECLARE @cutoff int
SET @cutoff = 5

SELECT
      UserId
    , ExerciseID
    , Score
    , ExcerciseUsers
    , UserExcercises
FROM (
            SELECT
                  UserId
                , ExerciseID
                , Score
                , COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY UserID)            AS ExcerciseUsers
                , COUNT(case when score = 1 then score end) OVER (PARTITION BY ExerciseID) AS UserExcercises
            FROM FrenchExercises
      ) AS derived
WHERE ExcerciseUsers >= @cutoff
      AND UserExcercises >= @cutoff
ORDER BY
      UserId
      , ExerciseID
;
```

<kbd>[Demo3 - amended sample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/34555/5)</kbd>

Comment: I cannot check your answer at the moment, but will do so tomorrow. As for your assumptions, you are right on the active part, although it should be 20 times or more in the resulting table. As for your second assumption, a completed exercise is just an exercise where there is a record of. The Score column indicates how well they did on that exercise. As long as there is a record (the score column is irrelevant) in the original table then that means the user has completed that exercise. Your third assumption is correct, there are no duplicated as stated in the original post.

Comment: any news from testing?

Comment: I'm sorry, at the moment I'm in a very busy schedule and I'm afraid I'll have to postpone answerring this question. I working on other stuff to meet a deadline the 25th. After that I'll try getting some test data ready to reproduce my situation.